# Apache can't display Drone via ProxyPass

Tags: windows, apache, docker, cloudflare, drone.io

#### Problem

I followed this [Drone Setup Tutorial](http://readme.drone.io/admin/installation-guide/) but I didn't manage to get Drone CI correctly setup with an Apache server:

- Drone does response to any requests when I tried to access it over an
  IP. (In my case: `http://192.168.99.100:8000/`)
- But I can't access Drone over domain addresses via Apache. (such as: `https://drone.suriyaa.tk/`)

---

#### Screenshots

The output from `drone-agent_1` in debug mode under Docker Quickstart Terminal on Windows 10:

[image: Output from <code>drone-agent_1</code> in debug mode]

Drone works perfect with IPs:

[image: Drone under an IP]

But Drone can't be served and displayed with Apache under a domain address:

[image: Drone under a domain address]

---

#### Information about the configurations

My `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '2'

services:
  drone-server:
    image: drone/drone:0.5
    environment:
      DRONE_ADMIN: <an_admin_user>
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    volumes:
      - C:\Users\Suriyaa\Downloads\DRONE\var\lib\drone:/var/lib/drone/
    restart: always
    environment:
      - DRONE_HOST=http://192.168.99.100
      - DRONE_OPEN=true
      - DRONE_GITHUB=true
      - DRONE_GITHUB_URL=https://github.com
      - DRONE_GITHUB_CLIENT=<github_client_id>
      - DRONE_GITHUB_SECRET=<github_secret>
      - DRONE_GITHUB_SCOPE=repo,repo:status,user:email,read:org
      - DRONE_GITHUB_CONTEXT=continuous-integration/drone
      - DRONE_GITHUB_SKIP_VERIFY=false
      - DRONE_SECRET=<secret>

  drone-agent:
    image: drone/drone:0.5
    command: agent
    restart: always
    depends_on: [ drone-server ]
      - C:\Users\Suriyaa\Downloads\DRONE\var\run\docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    environment:
      - DRONE_SERVER=ws://192.168.99.100:8000/ws/broker
      - DRONE_SECRET=<secret>
```

My virtual host configuration under Apache:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName drone.suriyaa.tk
    ServerAlias drone.suriyaa.tk
    ServerAdmin <an_email_address>

    BufferedLogs On

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests off

    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"

    ProxyPass /ws/ ws://192.168.99.100:8000/ws/
    ProxyPassReverse /ws/ ws://192.168.99.100:8000/ws/

    ProxyPass / http://192.168.99.100:8000/ retry=1 acquire=3000 timeout=600 Keepalive=On
    ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.99.100:8000/
</VirtualHost>
```

I already enabled important Apache modules for Drone:

- `mod_headers`
- `mod_proxy`
- `mod_proxy_http`
- `mod_proxy_wstunnel`

> So how can I fix the issue?

---

**EDIT:**

I get the same HTML content at https://drone.suriyaa.tk/ and http://192.168.99.100:8000/:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport"/>
<meta content="ie=edge" http-equiv="x-ua-compatible"/>
<script src="/cdn-cgi/apps/head/IS7ZAp3ID1yi0rZxe4CgzJCotFY.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
try{if (!window.CloudFlare) {var CloudFlare=[{verbose:0,p:0,byc:0,owlid:"cf",bag2:1,mirage2:0,oracle:0,paths:{cloudflare:"/cdn-cgi/nexp/dok3v=1613a3a185/"},atok:"650990d51d5b296f966a090423ea0b35",petok:"e2464cb008caccfc151874ac4f4f22d0e2b688b9-1500812575-1800",zone:"suriyaa.tk",rocket:"a",apps:{}}];document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/nexp/dok3v=85b614c0f6/cloudflare.min.js"><'+'\/script>');}}catch(e){};
//]]>
</script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Mono" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/static/app.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/static/favicon.ico" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon"/>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app"></div>
<script type="text/rocketscript">
  window.STATE_FROM_SERVER={"csrf":"","user":null};
</script>
<script data-rocketsrc="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.3/material.min.js" type="text/rocketscript"></script>
<script data-rocketsrc="/static/app.js" type="text/rocketscript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here are the debug output of my browser:
[image: Debug the Console (in Firefox Aurora)]
[image: Debug the Network (in Firefox Aurora)]

> I think Cloudflare blocks the content.

---

#### Helpful resources

- https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/219304477
- https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/203564960
- https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/217471977

Answer (score 0):

In the `drone-server` section of your docker-compose file set `DRONE_HOST` to

```
DRONE_HOST=drone.suriyaa.tk
```

Also, you should use `DRONE_SERVER=ws://drone-server:8000/ws/broker` in the agent config.

Comment: It doesn't work. I set `DRONE_HOST` to `drone.suriyaa.tk` and `DRONE_SERVER` to `ws://drone-server:8000/ws/broker`.

Comment: Any errors in the Network or Console tab of your browser's dev tools? 

If drone mixes the `drone.suriyaa.tk` address and the IP when loading js and the ws:// endpoint then CORS will prevent that from working.